# Print detected classes after using Tensorflow Hub for an Object Detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, tensorflow-hub

I would like to use the [Tensorflow Hub Example Code](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/object_detection) for a little Project.
I don't know how to write a function to print out all the selected classes and scores after the output of the image with boxes. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution.

You have to edit the "draw_boxes" function and add a "object_list.append(display_str)" function in the for loop & then print the object_list after the loop